# Mouseover code is not working in selenium webdriver. Iam using below code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("liOrganizations"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action mouseOver = builder.moveToElement(element).build();
mouseOver.perform();
```

Firefox version: 18.0.2
selenium: 2.30.0

Comment: Without any further information, I think that it will be hard to help you. Please explain a little bit more context and if possible show us the HTML page.

Comment: please explain it properly for better answers..

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? If so, what exception?

Answer (score 0):

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("liOrganizations"));

new actions(driver).moveToElement(mo).perform();

Thread.sleep(2000);

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

`Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);`
`WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));`
`action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();`